# When is "dress" a mass noun?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, uncountable-nouns, countability, countable-nouns

I find the singular/uncountable usage of "dress" strange in this sentence.

> Expansive skirts on **fashionable dress** of the period proved the perfect blank canvas to showcase chintzes lush with pomegranates and lotus flowers à la Indiennes. ([source](https://www.vogue.com/article/braquenie-tree-of-life-history))

According to [Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/dress_2), "dress" is a mass noun only with reference to "the clothes that are typical of a particular place, time in history, or occasion", such as "military dress." This is also supported by Cambridge Dictionary, which has more examples of "dress" as a mass noun. This sentence apparently does not fit this usage. I thought it should be

> Expansive skirts on **fashionable dresses** of the period proved the perfect blank canvas to showcase chintzes lush with pomegranates and lotus flowers à la Indiennes.

Is the original text mistaken?

Comment: Does it make sense if you think of it as "expansive skirts on fashionable ***period dress***"?

Comment: Since the definition says "the clothes that are typical of a particular place, time in history", I think that is the reasonable way to understand "fashionable dress of the period".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your suggestion and the original are both possible. They would simply have different meanings.

> The cut of skirts of fashionable dress (i.e. wear, clothing) of the
>   period tended to be well above the knee.
>
> The sleeves of fashionable dresses of the period tended to extend to
>   the wrist.

When **dress** means "typical clothing" in the first example, it might include a woman's business suit with a short skirt, say, or a casual skirt and blouse ensemble, that is, a number of different kinds of outfits all of which could fall under the rubric "the dress of the period considered 'fashionable' or 'with the times' ".